# Is it possible to flag users who use photos of very young children, or is there an age limit for Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, specific-flag

In Stack Exchange communities, like Math.SE, are users allowed to have profile photos of children?

I would like to know whether or not it is correct to flag those profiles where there are pictures of children.. They could also be photos of other people.

Comment: I'm not really sure I get your question... what children are you talking about who need protection?

Comment: What do you mean with " flag the users = childs" also what do you mean with "profiles with photo of guys, childs"? There is a lower limit for the age of user (13 and 16 for some areas); thus  if you suspect a user is too young for the site, you should flag it. If you see inherently inappropriate user-pictures you should also flag time. I do not think that you should flag pictures with children in general.But I might miss the point. (Maybe it is that the adult user might have posted the picture of the child without the child's consent,  but really I am not sure this is an issue for us.)

Comment: Some users use a picture of their pet for the profile/gravatar.  That doesn't mean we have cats and dogs pretending to be users.  I suspect there are users who post pics of their child(ren).  That doesn't mean the child(ren) is/are the users.

Comment: @quid Yes, and you can edit my bad English language. It is correct your comment.

Comment: @Sebastiano I could if I would understand what you want to ask.

Comment: @quid There is a young guy (with photo) that he has asked a question on the graphs. Now I not have finded him.

Comment: @quid I have edited my title. I hope that now it is more clear.

Comment: If any user posts any pornographic picture, @Sabastiano, then indeed such a child is in need of protection.  Flag immediiately. But if a user posts a picture of their 5th grader singing in a chorus, don't flag.  Such a picture is not a picture of a child in need of protection.

Comment: @amWhy Ok. Thank you very much. But is there a limit of age for subscribe on math.SE?

Comment: Yes there is the requirement, as has been stated, that a user be 13 years old or older.  But you seem not to have understood my comment that having a profile pic of a child doesn't mean that account is owned by that child.  Parents, like pet owners, are often proud of their children, and or pets, and may use photos of their child or pet, as a profile pic.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I have understood your first comment. Don't worry. Thank you very much.

Comment: My friend Dmitry now uses a picture of himself, perhaps age 5, as an avatar online. He is about 60 years old, he says he did not want to use a picture of himself at age 40 and have people claim he was attempting to appear younger. We went through some early pictures of me, he said they were not right (none had just my face, as a passport picture) so we went back to a picture of me at about age 40. At least on gmail, I still see my randomized red and white symbol above for MSE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are quite a few users who use photos of their children as avatars. A prime example is [one of the Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija). There's nothing wrong with that :)

If you do see a user who claims to be younger than 13 years, or see an equivalent statement about their current grade (pay close attention as those might differ per country), they're [not allowed to use the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770/295232) you can do two things:

- use the [Contact Us](/contact) form
- flag one of their posts for ♦ moderator attention – they have access to more information than you, but will usually forward the deletion request to the Community Team; there's a special option for that in the moderator tools

In both cases, please include where you found the evidence (the post, their profile, a comment or chat message)

Comment: It's the users who act like they're under 13 that I worry about.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True, that!